# Visual Studio for Mac does not get past "Add packages"

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am trying out Xamarin Forms on Visual Studio for Mac.

When I create a new project, I see VS is trying to add packages to the solution, but every single time- it fails at the same place...

Here is the Package Console output:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-KfdWC2hub4YuEOHfJ_LICL86o6zkecytmMAi0emDeQ

On this new project, after the package installer fails, it always fails to build with the default assets:[image: styles.xml]

Is it possible other dev environments are affecting Visual Studio?

Is there a more stable way I can use Xamarin forms on a Mac?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the errors I see in your Package Console is:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v2.3', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

NuGet looks at your project's target framework and version to see if the NuGet packages are compatible. As far as NuGet is aware your project is targeting MonoAndroid version 2.3. Check what you have selected as the **Compile using Android version** in the project properties and ensure that it's compatible with the package you want to add.

Also, a "more stable" way to use Xamarin Forms on a Mac is not available unless you want to try Xamarin Studio but that is almost the same as Visual Studio for Mac (which is based on it).

Comment: That's the problem though, I am not adding any packages manually, visual studio is automatically launching NuGet in a completely fresh project, with a clean install of VS for Mac.

Comment: Do you have everything up to date when running **Check for updates** and are you running the Stable channel?

Comment: Also, Xamarin Android 2.3 is a pretty old version. Somehow it is defaulting back to that. You can also check which Android SDKs you have installed when going up to Tools > SDK Manager. Make sure you have some of the newer versions of Android installed (5, 6, 7).

Comment: Yeah, everything is up to date. When creating the app you can select the level of compatibility you would like, I have now selected the medium option and it seems to run fine (mostly).

Comment: Did you select Maximum the first time around? If so that means it targets Android 2.3 as well and the newer support packages apparently don't support 2.3 anymore.

Comment: Yeah, weird it would be included in the program if it is no longer supported. This far I have only been able to get Xamarin.Android to work, but Xamarin.Forms still refuses to compile